# How to add a new command line option to symfony console

Tags: symfony

I am not an expert in Symfony, I need to add a new console option `--country=XX` to the symfony console.

This isnt a command, its an option which changes how whatever command is run, executes by selecting a different database to operate on by building the doctrine.dbal.dbname parameter such as `api_fr`, `api_de`, `api_es`, etc.

I have tried to search for a way to do this, but unfortunately everything comes back to adding commands, which is not what I want to do, I want to add an option.

I am building an API which part of it works with Symfony 2.8 and another part is using Symfony 3.x. I suppose the answer might be the same in both versions, but if you know how to do this in both versions and they are separate, please let me know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add an EventListener like this exemple:

```
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;

class YourOptionEventListener
{
    public function onConsoleCommand(ConsoleCommandEvent $event)
    {
        $inputDefinition = $event->getCommand()->getApplication()->getDefinition();

        // add the option to the application's input definition
        $inputDefinition->addOption(
            new InputOption('yourOption', null, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, 'Description of the option', null)
        );
    }
}
```

Then add it as a service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<container ...>
    <services>
        <service id="app_yourOption.console_event_listener"
                 class="App\YourOptionBundle\EventListener\YourOptionEventListener">
            <tag name="kernel.event_listener" event="console.command" method="onConsoleCommand" />
        </service>
    </services>
</container>
```

You can check this documentation, in "Add a global command option" chapter, you can find what you need:
http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2013/11/symfony2-add-a-global-option-to-console-commands-and-generate-pid-file/

Answer (score 3):

The best practice of **2018 and Symfony 3+** is to extend Symfony Application:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;

final class SomeApplication extends Application
{
    protected function getDefaultInputDefinition()
    {
        $definition = parent::getDefaultInputDefinition();
        $definition->addOption(new InputOption(
            'country',
            null,
            InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED,
            'Country to use'
        ));

        return $definition;
    }
}
```

Then anywhere in your command or service with `Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterace` service present, just call:

```
$country = $input->getOption('country');
```

#### Do you want to know more?

I've **extended the answer** in the [4 Ways to Add Global Option or Argument to Symfony Console Application](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2018/09/03/4-ways-to-add-global-option-or-argument-to-symfony-console-application/) post.

Comment: thanks, should be accepted answer for latest Symfony